# media player does not load when activity is recreated on orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-orientation, android-framelayout

I am new to play a video in video player using surface view now i want to save instance state of media player when orientation change when view reloaded or recreated then old media player state start at old position not to load on original means at zero position i set in manifest like screen orientation but that time oncreate not called i want to call also oncreate method when screen orientation change means to say i want to reload a new activity when orientation change and also save media player state please acknowledge i am stuck at that time i don't know what mistake.

```
 SurfaceView videoSurface;
         MediaPlayer player;
        VideoControllerView controller;
        private boolean mFullScreen = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);



                videoSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
                SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
                videoHolder.addCallback(this);

                player = new MediaPlayer();
                controller = new VideoControllerView(this);

                try {
                    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
                    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                controller.show();
                return false;
            }

            // Implement SurfaceHolder.Callback
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
              player.setDisplay(holder);
              player.prepareAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            }
            // End SurfaceHolder.Callback

            // Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
                controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
                player.start();
            }
            // End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

            // Implement VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
            @Override
            public boolean canPause() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canSeekBackward() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canSeekForward() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public int getBufferPercentage() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCurrentPosition() {
                return player.getCurrentPosition();
            }

            @Override
            public int getDuration() {
                return player.getDuration();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isPlaying() {
                return player.isPlaying();
            }

            @Override
            public void pause() {
                player.pause();
            }

            @Override
            public void seekTo(int i) {
                player.seekTo(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void start() {
                player.start();
            }



            @Override
        public boolean isFullScreen() {
            if(mFullScreen){
                Log.w("FullScreen", "--set icon full screen--");
                Log.w("curr",player.getCurrentPosition()+"");
            /*    ImageButton mFullscreenButton=(ImageButton)controller.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
                mFullscreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_stretch);
               */ return false;
            }else{
                Log.w("FullScreen", "--set icon small full screen--");
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void toggleFullScreen() {
            Log.w("FullScreen", "-----------------click toggleFullScreen-----------");
            setFullScreen(isFullScreen());

        }
        // End VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl

        public void setFullScreen(boolean fullScreen){
            fullScreen = false;

            if (mFullScreen)

            {
                Log.w("FullScreen", "-----------Set full screen SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE------------");

                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = width;
                params.height=height;
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                //set icon is full screen
                mFullScreen = fullScreen;
            }
            else{
                Log.w("FullScreen", "-----------Set small screen SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT------------");
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                final FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer);
                // int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                int height =225;//get height Frame Container video//mFrame.getHeight()
                int width =displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = width;
                params.height= height;
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                //set icon is small screen
                mFullScreen = !fullScreen;
            }
        }
       @Override
       protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estadoguardado){

           super.onSaveInstanceState(estadoguardado);
           if(player!=null){

               int pos=player.getCurrentPosition();
               estadoguardado.putInt("posicion", pos);
           }

       }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle estadoguardado)
        {

            super.onRestoreInstanceState(estadoguardado);
            if(estadoguardado!=null && player!=null){
                int pos=estadoguardado.getInt("posicion");
                Log.w("position",pos+"");
                player.seekTo(pos);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {


            super.onResume();
            try {
                //reinicia
                Toast.makeText(this, "onResume2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (player == null)
                    player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
                player.seekTo(0);
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause()
        {
            super.onPause();
            Toast.makeText(this, "onPause2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //LIBERA A MEDIA PLAYER
            if (player != null)
            {
                player.release();
                player = null;
            }
```

and other class which extend from frameLayout

and some crashes when app going to run

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
            at whizpool.videoplayerexample.VideoPlayerActivity.surfaceCreated(VideoPlayerActivity.java:70)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:554)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:693)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1762)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511   
10-12 10:00:48.726    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x18332b8, mCurrentState=2
10-12 10:00:48.726    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
10-12 10:00:48.727    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
10-12 10:00:48.727    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
10-12 10:00:48.738    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
10-12 10:00:48.738    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
10-12 10:00:48.885    2268-2268/whizpool.videoplayerexample E/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync called in state 0
```

Comment: I think you should add code to onResume() if it is not initialization code only..!!

Comment: means to say i uncomment onResume() code..!!

Comment: Yes..Please uncomment code of `onResume`!!

Comment: @Override
    public void onResume()
    {


        super.onResume();
        try {
            //reinicia
            Toast.makeText(this, "onResume2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (player == null)
                player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
            player.seekTo(0);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  when i added this code my app crashes its give that error which is in next comment

Comment: at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
            at whizpool.videoplayerexample.VideoPlayerActivity.surfaceCreated(VideoPlayerActivity.java:70)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:554)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:693)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1762)
            at

Comment: Remove this comment and add this to your edited question so others can also see this..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the orientation to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR after a few seconds so the sensor will start to work again..

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
>
> new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>
>         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
>
>     }
> }, 2000);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To save and resume video positions when rotating you need to utilise onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState. You can save the video position from a VideoView with this code.

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    if (videoView.canPause()) {
        videoView.pause();
    }

    outState.putInt(VIDEO_POSITION_KEY, videoPosition);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState() Current Position Saved is: " + videoPosition);
}
```

...and retrieve it again with this code.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    videoPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(VIDEO_POSITION_KEY, 0);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState() - Seeking to position:" + Integer.toString(videoPosition));
    videoView.seekTo(videoPosition); // this call should keep the video at the saved position
}
```

Comment: i  am using surfaceview not video view which is mention in code and tried this code but failed